# how to run react project with web pack which contains frontend and backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am having problem with running the project, the project is contains the frontend(react) and backend(node) how should run the frontend side for the project

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "' open source project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "node src/backend/main.js",
    "watch": "webpack --mode=development -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": { "type": "git", "url": "" },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": { "url": "" },
  "homepage": ""
}
```

Comment: Are you able to share the `scripts` within the `package.json`?

Comment: For development, in production, or both?

Comment: Yes its for both @madflow

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run frontend(React) and backend(Node) at the same time install concurrently and nodemon.

```
npm i concurrently 
npm install -g nodemon
```

then at the package.json file add concurrently to run both frontend and backend together.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "backend": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "frontend": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run backend\" \"npm run start --prefix client\""
  },
```

If you want to run only your frontend go to client folder and open your terminal and type

```
npm start or yarn start
```

Comment: There no client folder @Fahad

Comment: The folder that contains your react files is named as client.You can name that anything

Comment: please elaborate i am beginner i am having only one package.json  and that should running backend part not frontend @Fahad

Comment: @Fahad how do I replace the front end with yarn instead of npm run start --prefix client